# Develop Volatility Stop (Average True Range Trailing Stop) Indicator in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, function, pine-script

I recently started learning Python and trying to develop "Volatility Stop" indicator in Python from Trading View Pine Script.

**Following is Trading View Pine Script.**

```
//@version=5
indicator("Volatility Stop", "VStop", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
length = input.int(3, "Length", minval = 2)
src = input.source(low, "Source")
factor = input.float(2.0, "Multiplier", minval = 0.25, step = 0.25)
volStop(src, atrlen, atrfactor) =>
    if not na(src)
        var max     = src
        var min     = src
        var uptrend = true
        var float stop    = na
        atrM        = nz(ta.atr(atrlen) * atrfactor, ta.tr)
        max         := math.max(max, src)
        min         := math.min(min, src)
        stop        := nz(uptrend ? math.max(stop, max - atrM) : math.min(stop, min + atrM), src)
        uptrend     := src - stop >= 0.0
        if uptrend != nz(uptrend[1], true)
            max    := src
            min    := src
            stop   := uptrend ? max - atrM : min + atrM
        [stop, uptrend]

[vStop, uptrend] = volStop(src, length, factor)

plot(vStop, "Volatility Stop", style=plot.style_cross, color= uptrend ? #009688 : #F44336)
```

**Following is Python Function.**

```
def Volatility_Stop(Data_Column, High_Price, Low_Price, Close_Price, window, Multiplier):

  TR = np.max(pd.concat([(High_Price - Low_Price), abs(High_Price - Close_Price.shift(1)), abs(Low_Price - Close_Price.shift(1))], axis=1), axis=1)

  ATR = TR.ewm(alpha=1/window, min_periods=window, adjust=False).mean()

  ATR_Multiplier = ATR * Multiplier

  ATR_Multiplier = ATR_Multiplier.fillna(TR).tolist()

  Up_Trend_List = []
  Volatility_Stop_List = []

  Max_Price_List = []
  Min_Price_List = []

  for i in range(0, len(Data_Column)):

    if i == 0:

      Up_Trend = True
      Volatility_Stop = Data_Column[i]

      max_price = Data_Column[i]
      min_price = Data_Column[i]

      Up_Trend_List.append(Up_Trend)
      Volatility_Stop_List.append(Volatility_Stop)

      Max_Price_List.append(max_price)
      Min_Price_List.append(min_price)

    if i > 0:

      Up_Trend = Data_Column[i] - Volatility_Stop_List[i-1]

      if Up_Trend >= 0:

        max_price = max(Max_Price_List[i-1], Data_Column[i])

        Volatility_Stop = max(Volatility_Stop_List[i-1], max_price - ATR_Multiplier[i])

      else:

        min_price = min(Min_Price_List[i-1], Data_Column[i])

        Volatility_Stop = min(Volatility_Stop_List[i-1], min_price + ATR_Multiplier[i])

      if np.isnan(Volatility_Stop) == True:

        Volatility_Stop = Data_Column[i]

      if Up_Trend != Up_Trend_List[i-1]:

        max_price = Data_Column[i]
        min_price = Data_Column[i]

        if Up_Trend >= 0:

          Volatility_Stop = max_price - ATR_Multiplier[i]

        else:

          Volatility_Stop = min_price + ATR_Multiplier[i]

      Up_Trend_List.append(Up_Trend)
      Volatility_Stop_List.append(Volatility_Stop)

      Max_Price_List.append(max_price)
      Min_Price_List.append(min_price)

  Volatility_Stop_List = pd.Series(Volatility_Stop_List, index=Data_Column.index)

  return Volatility_Stop_List
```

**Python Function Output is NOT matching with Trading View.** Only few values (during down tread) is matching.

**Refer to *"Difference (Python Output - Pine Script Output)"* Column for discrepancy.**

Following is DataFrame with Python Function and Trading View column.

```
data['Python Function Output'] = Volatility_Stop(data['Low'], data['High'], data['Low'], data['Close'], 3, 2)
```

| Date | Open | High | Low | Close | Python Function Output | DESIRE Pine Script Output | Difference (Python Output - Pine Script Output) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-23 | 9,622.00 | 9,622.00 | 9,300.00 | 9,301.00 | 9,300.000000 | 9,300.000000 | - |
| 2018-01-24 | 9,176.00 | 9,534.00 | 9,036.20 | 9,344.40 | 9,534.000000 | 9,534.000000 | - |
| 2018-01-25 | 9,162.00 | 9,426.00 | 9,050.00 | 9,340.00 | 9,808.133247 | 9,534.000000 | 274 |
| 2018-01-26 | 9,042.00 | 9,173.60 | 8,588.00 | 8,657.60 | 9,594.755498 | 9,534.000000 | 61 |
| 2018-01-29 | 8,729.60 | 8,744.00 | 8,400.00 | 8,400.00 | 9,300.503665 | 9,317.854815 | - 17 |
| 2018-01-30 | 8,910.00 | 8,924.00 | 8,528.00 | 8,670.00 | 9,477.669110 | 9,317.854815 | 160 |
| 2018-01-31 | 8,396.00 | 8,582.60 | 8,310.00 | 8,559.80 | 9,183.112740 | 9,190.824362 | - 8 |
| 2018-02-01 | 8,934.00 | 8,934.00 | 8,400.00 | 8,524.00 | 9,338.075160 | 9,190.824362 | 147 |
| 2018-02-02 | 8,926.00 | 9,326.00 | 8,737.40 | 9,300.20 | 9,897.450497 | 9,190.824362 | 707 |
| 2018-02-05 | 9,818.00 | 10,460.00 | 9,173.60 | 10,460.00 | 10,804.566608 | 9,190.824362 | 1,614 |
| 2018-02-06 | 10,700.00 | 11,554.00 | 9,598.00 | 9,604.00 | 11,989.311332 | 7,205.165558 | 4,784 |
| 2018-02-07 | 9,580.00 | 9,792.00 | 9,233.20 | 9,656.00 | 11,199.940953 | 7,630.243705 | 3,570 |
| 2018-02-08 | 9,640.00 | 10,627.00 | 8,574.00 | 10,627.00 | 11,253.827172 | 7,630.243705 | 3,624 |
| 2018-02-09 | 9,900.00 | 11,200.00 | 9,850.00 | 10,175.80 | 12,536.551448 | 7,630.243705 | 4,906 |
| 2018-02-12 | 9,527.40 | 10,100.00 | 9,527.40 | 9,606.00 | 11,750.700965 | 7,630.243705 | 4,120 |
| 2018-02-13 | 9,776.00 | 9,776.00 | 9,023.00 | 9,097.80 | 11,007.200383 | 7,865.643201 | 3,142 |
| 2018-02-14 | 8,850.00 | 8,850.00 | 8,340.00 | 8,352.00 | 10,168.000125 | 8,021.895467 | 2,146 |
| 2018-02-15 | 8,126.00 | 8,391.80 | 7,878.00 | 7,878.00 | 9,439.199953 | 9,434.269688 | 5 |
| 2018-02-16 | 7,978.00 | 8,125.80 | 7,867.00 | 8,019.60 | 9,080.333172 | 9,080.353126 | - 0 |
| 2018-02-20 | 8,162.00 | 8,162.00 | 7,684.00 | 8,000.00 | 8,811.555448 | 8,811.622084 | - 0 |
| 2018-02-21 | 7,800.00 | 7,840.00 | 7,420.20 | 7,840.00 | 8,558.437030 | 8,558.481389 | - 0 |
| 2018-02-22 | 8,200.00 | 8,200.00 | 7,686.00 | 7,893.60 | 8,787.491223 | 8,521.720926 | 266 |
| 2018-02-23 | 7,760.00 | 7,760.00 | 7,484.60 | 7,490.20 | 8,491.594247 | 8,427.227284 | 64 |
| 2018-02-26 | 7,400.00 | 7,656.00 | 7,262.00 | 7,266.00 | 8,195.996099 | 8,196.018189 | - 0 |
| 2018-02-27 | 7,266.80 | 7,564.00 | 7,260.00 | 7,550.00 | 8,085.330733 | 8,085.345460 | - 0 |
| 2018-02-28 | 7,407.00 | 7,656.00 | 7,407.00 | 7,656.00 | 8,123.220489 | 7,976.230306 | 147 |
| 2018-03-01 | 7,760.00 | 8,312.00 | 7,650.00 | 8,026.00 | 8,568.813659 | 7,976.230306 | 593 |
| 2018-03-02 | 8,370.00 | 8,600.00 | 7,707.00 | 7,800.00 | 8,914.875773 | 7,976.230306 | 939 |
| 2018-03-05 | 7,947.80 | 7,947.80 | 7,264.00 | 7,266.00 | 8,525.117052 | 7,976.230306 | 549 |
| 2018-03-06 | 7,188.00 | 7,241.00 | 7,015.20 | 7,074.00 | 8,023.144766 | 7,976.230306 | 47 |
| 2018-03-07 | 7,233.20 | 7,262.00 | 6,928.40 | 6,944.00 | 7,822.763015 | 7,822.815349 | - 0 |
| 2018-03-08 | 6,860.00 | 7,097.80 | 6,860.00 | 7,050.00 | 7,614.775278 | 7,614.756899 | 0 |
| 2018-03-09 | 7,122.00 | 7,122.00 | 6,632.00 | 6,632.00 | 7,461.850185 | 7,461.837933 | 0 |
| 2018-03-12 | 6,484.00 | 6,502.00 | 6,377.60 | 6,425.60 | 7,100.433489 | 7,100.438622 | - 0 |
| 2018-03-13 | 6,378.00 | 6,886.20 | 6,378.00 | 6,850.00 | 7,198.689058 | 7,100.438622 | 98 |
| 2018-03-14 | 6,732.00 | 6,732.00 | 6,470.00 | 6,600.00 | 7,270.459372 | 7,100.438622 | 170 |
| 2018-03-15 | 6,512.40 | 6,675.20 | 6,453.60 | 6,520.20 | 7,134.973077 | 7,058.952184 | 76 |
| 2018-03-16 | 6,669.80 | 6,698.00 | 6,614.00 | 6,631.00 | 7,186.781856 | 6,950.381456 | 236 |
| 2018-03-19 | 6,998.00 | 7,376.00 | 6,890.00 | 7,200.00 | 7,768.521238 | 6,950.381456 | 818 |
| 2018-03-20 | 7,342.00 | 7,501.00 | 7,072.20 | 7,328.00 | 7,943.747557 | 6,200.679353 | 1,743 |
| 2018-03-21 | 7,411.00 | 7,411.00 | 7,104.00 | 7,330.00 | 7,889.698241 | 6,318.359569 | 1,571 |
| 2018-03-22 | 7,771.80 | 8,066.00 | 7,526.20 | 8,040.00 | 8,540.665689 | 6,511.773046 | 2,029 |
| 2018-03-23 | 8,040.00 | 8,633.00 | 8,040.00 | 8,600.00 | 9,111.643663 | 6,661.748697 | 2,450 |
| 2018-03-26 | 7,986.00 | 8,812.00 | 7,737.00 | 7,737.00 | 9,168.095775 | 6,661.748697 | 2,506 |
| 2018-03-27 | 7,640.00 | 9,258.00 | 7,640.00 | 8,999.40 | 9,672.730517 | 6,661.748697 | 3,011 |
| 2018-03-28 | 9,580.00 | 10,010.80 | 9,130.00 | 9,707.60 | 11,159.419954 | 7,064.265540 | 4,095 |
| 2018-03-29 | 9,998.00 | 10,000.00 | 8,756.00 | 8,950.00 | 10,938.279969 | 7,064.265540 | 3,874 |
| 2018-04-02 | 9,420.00 | 10,168.00 | 9,230.40 | 9,846.00 | 11,497.253703 | 7,064.265540 | 4,433 |
| 2018-04-03 | 9,426.00 | 10,060.00 | 9,282.60 | 9,646.40 | 11,312.102078 | 7,242.232012 | 4,070 |
| 2018-04-04 | 10,358.00 | 10,384.00 | 9,154.00 | 9,154.00 | 11,327.001646 | 7,242.232012 | 4,085 |
| 2018-04-05 | 8,832.00 | 8,943.20 | 8,625.80 | 8,760.00 | 10,426.601032 | 7,476.923116 | 2,950 |
| 2018-04-06 | 8,970.00 | 9,466.00 | 8,762.80 | 9,306.00 | 10,434.000623 | 7,608.128744 | 2,826 |
| 2018-04-09 | 9,006.00 | 9,200.00 | 8,712.00 | 9,200.00 | 10,222.133879 | 7,770.265829 | 2,452 |
| 2018-04-10 | 8,758.00 | 8,838.00 | 8,180.00 | 8,220.00 | 9,866.755919 | 7,770.265829 | 2,096 |
| 2018-04-11 | 8,404.00 | 8,960.00 | 8,114.20 | 8,372.00 | 9,802.570678 | 7,770.265829 | 2,032 |
| 2018-04-12 | 8,200.00 | 8,298.00 | 8,090.00 | 8,209.80 | 9,403.580322 | 7,968.378764 | 1,435 |
| 2018-04-13 | 8,020.00 | 8,420.00 | 7,988.80 | 8,307.00 | 9,151.986816 | 9,152.400824 | - 0 |
| 2018-04-16 | 8,200.00 | 8,496.00 | 8,200.00 | 8,304.00 | 9,172.791341 | 8,961.893883 | 211 |
| 2018-04-17 | 8,000.00 | 8,002.00 | 7,333.80 | 7,382.20 | 8,629.127496 | 8,629.269255 | - 0 |
| 2018-04-18 | 7,382.00 | 7,457.80 | 7,242.00 | 7,320.60 | 8,249.418330 | 8,249.526170 | - 0 |
| 2018-04-19 | 7,366.20 | 7,570.00 | 7,268.00 | 7,338.80 | 8,140.945554 | 8,115.004113 | 26 |
| 2018-04-20 | 7,457.00 | 7,800.00 | 7,400.00 | 7,720.00 | 8,289.430499 | 8,115.004113 | 174 |
| 2018-04-23 | 7,662.00 | 8,100.00 | 7,594.00 | 8,014.20 | 8,524.286999 | 8,115.004113 | 409 |
| 2018-04-24 | 7,927.60 | 8,800.00 | 7,860.00 | 8,555.60 | 9,106.858000 | 8,115.004113 | 992 |
| 2018-04-25 | 8,458.00 | 9,291.80 | 8,458.00 | 8,757.80 | 9,845.105203 | 7,070.856471 | 2,774 |
| 2018-04-26 | 8,302.00 | 8,302.00 | 7,852.20 | 7,999.60 | 9,380.670070 | 7,070.856471 | 2,310 |
| 2018-04-27 | 7,526.00 | 8,304.00 | 7,400.00 | 7,720.20 | 9,021.646583 | 7,070.856471 | 1,951 |
| 2018-04-30 | 7,600.00 | 7,882.20 | 7,442.00 | 7,661.60 | 8,816.564519 | 7,083.358955 | 1,733 |
| 2018-05-01 | 7,828.00 | 7,848.00 | 7,504.00 | 7,514.00 | 8,649.709679 | 7,312.239303 | 1,337 |
| 2018-05-02 | 7,324.00 | 7,440.80 | 7,080.20 | 7,300.00 | 8,133.206518 | 8,133.240465 | - 0 |
| 2018-05-03 | 7,600.00 | 7,820.00 | 7,337.00 | 7,337.00 | 8,385.670882 | 8,128.893643 | 257 |
| 2018-05-04 | 7,594.00 | 7,594.00 | 6,876.40 | 6,906.00 | 8,053.913889 | 8,053.915762 | - 0 |
| 2018-05-07 | 6,713.80 | 6,713.80 | 6,440.00 | 6,580.00 | 7,535.675991 | 7,535.703841 | - 0 |
| 2018-05-08 | 6,600.00 | 6,648.00 | 6,400.00 | 6,439.40 | 7,295.783994 | 7,295.789228 | - 0 |
| 2018-05-09 | 6,400.00 | 6,400.00 | 6,200.00 | 6,215.00 | 6,956.789264 | 6,956.766152 | 0 |
| 2018-05-10 | 6,204.00 | 6,204.00 | 5,952.00 | 6,000.00 | 6,631.859509 | 6,631.844101 | 0 |
| 2018-05-11 | 5,990.00 | 6,201.80 | 5,990.00 | 6,124.00 | 6,584.439543 | 6,546.376067 | 38 |
| 2018-05-14 | 6,072.00 | 6,072.00 | 5,880.00 | 6,052.00 | 6,438.959695 | 6,438.917378 | 0 |
| 2018-05-15 | 6,270.00 | 6,420.00 | 6,270.00 | 6,378.00 | 6,887.973130 | 6,438.917378 | 449 |
| 2018-05-16 | 6,286.00 | 6,344.20 | 6,182.00 | 6,220.00 | 6,724.648753 | 6,422.616613 | 302 |
| 2018-05-17 | 6,228.00 | 6,336.00 | 6,044.00 | 6,271.80 | 6,600.432502 | 6,422.616613 | 178 |
| 2018-05-18 | 6,400.00 | 6,590.00 | 6,385.40 | 6,590.00 | 6,968.488367 | 6,422.616613 | 546 |
| 2018-05-21 | 6,260.00 | 6,580.00 | 6,206.00 | 6,451.00 | 6,850.725643 | 6,422.616613 | 428 |
| 2018-05-22 | 6,400.00 | 6,626.80 | 6,347.80 | 6,626.80 | 6,963.616900 | 6,422.616613 | 541 |
| 2018-05-23 | 6,800.00 | 6,800.00 | 6,344.60 | 6,344.60 | 7,058.744763 | 6,422.616613 | 636 |
| 2018-05-24 | 6,344.00 | 6,446.60 | 6,260.00 | 6,320.00 | 6,860.496509 | 6,422.616613 | 438 |
| 2018-05-25 | 6,274.00 | 6,274.00 | 6,172.00 | 6,216.00 | 6,670.997672 | 6,378.964978 | 292 |
| 2018-05-29 | 6,258.00 | 6,321.80 | 6,080.00 | 6,210.00 | 6,573.864985 | 6,373.843319 | 200 |
| 2018-05-30 | 6,126.20 | 6,248.00 | 6,070.00 | 6,070.00 | 6,517.909990 | 6,327.895546 | 190 |
| 2018-05-31 | 6,054.00 | 6,096.00 | 5,955.00 | 6,035.00 | 6,347.606660 | 6,272.597030 | 75 |
| 2018-06-01 | 5,928.00 | 5,928.00 | 5,600.00 | 5,615.00 | 6,151.737773 | 6,151.664687 | 0 |
| 2018-06-04 | 5,521.60 | 5,521.60 | 5,277.00 | 5,292.00 | 5,870.158516 | 5,870.176458 | - 0 |
| 2018-06-05 | 5,202.00 | 5,236.00 | 5,090.00 | 5,172.40 | 5,620.105677 | 5,620.090972 | 0 |
| 2018-06-06 | 5,100.20 | 5,212.00 | 5,030.00 | 5,030.00 | 5,504.737118 | 5,504.727315 | 0 |
| 2018-06-07 | 5,070.00 | 5,268.00 | 4,997.20 | 5,160.00 | 5,494.224810 | 5,494.204876 | 0 |
| 2018-06-08 | 5,259.00 | 5,262.00 | 5,078.20 | 5,111.80 | 5,532.083142 | 5,451.056584 | 81 |
| 2018-06-11 | 5,108.00 | 5,108.00 | 4,952.20 | 4,970.00 | 5,361.188566 | 5,361.251056 | - 0 |
| 2018-06-12 | 4,870.00 | 4,878.00 | 4,692.00 | 4,788.00 | 5,149.992247 | 5,150.034037 | - 0 |
| 2018-06-13 | 4,758.00 | 4,758.00 | 4,605.80 | 4,680.00 | 5,032.594766 | 5,032.596025 | - 0 |
| 2018-06-14 | 4,615.80 | 4,615.80 | 4,363.20 | 4,385.00 | 4,858.930039 | 4,859.004017 | - 0 |

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there sample (small) data + expected output. Also, explain please how the output should be computed. I think only few people can read Pine script.

Comment: @AndrejKesely
SAMPLE DataFrame and expected output is added. Please refer to following hyperlink for Calculation Steps**(https://download.esignal.com/products/workstation/help/charts/studies/wilders_volatility.htm)**